# how to check whether the row is focused or not (or) selected or not in if condition in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using master detail grid.when i click on the master grid row with focused row index, it must show the information in detail grid.fr that i have used check box to do that.i have checked checkbox if it is selected or not.but in my context checkbox not used so i have to get through focused row selection.
plz help me i tried for a days on tihis

```
for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
            object key = ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(i, "GLOBALID");

            if (ASPxGridView1.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case when you select the row you want to pass the Selected value to your Detailed GridView, you can then get the Selected Row value..

```
GridView1.SelectedValue // return selected row Data key value
```